# Notepad++ column mode: Go To Last Line

Tags: windows, text, notepad++

In a 200K+ line Notepad++ file, I need to **select a partial column (block)** of characters all the way **to the very last line**. (For example, select/highlight the block of 10th-15th characters, from the 100th line to the last line, but nothing outside of this perimeter.)

How can I extend the highlighted (by `Alt`-click) block of text downward to the last line without scroll-dragging the highlighted area?

In Windows PC, `Alt`-click and scrolling, `page down` works for smaller text blocks, but it takes forever to scroll to the last line in a large document. I tried various combinations of `Alt, Ctrl, Shift, down arrow, page down`, etc. none of them takes the cursor/highlighted text to the last line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + END

Comment: `CTRL + SHIFT + END` would take me to last line, but not in column editing mode (i.e, can not select a block of text in the middle of the document.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These steps should do it:

- Move your cursor to the 10th character on line 100.
- Use the scroll bar to scroll to the end of the file
- Hold Alt+Shift then click after the 15th character of the last line

It requires a little mouse movement, but should be very fast even in a large file.

Answer (score 8):

Position the cursor at the top left of your column. Then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> - then click on the bottom right of your column to select it in one go.

Comment: **_OK, the method:_** place **cursor before the first character** (top-left) of the block to be selected.
leave cursor there.
**scroll to the last line** with mouse by dragging the **sidebar**.
**hold down together `Ctrl Shift Alt` and
click after the last character** (bottom-right) of the block to be selected.

Comment: @user3026965 - why scroll/drag etc? Just CTRL + SHIFT + END to jump to the end in one go.

Comment: "Just CTRL + SHIFT + END to jump to the end in one go" does **not** select the block.

Comment: @user3026965 - sorry I think we have our wires crossed - no matter, the first bit is what you need.

Comment: thank you! do we need `Ctrl` for selection? it seems to be working w/o `Ctrl` as well.

Comment: Ha - maybe not - I have always pressed all three out of habit but I think you could be correct. 10 points to Gryffindor

Comment: No Ctrl Needed OK, the method: place cursor before the first character (top-left) of the block to be selected. leave cursor there. scroll to the last line with mouse by dragging the sidebar. hold down together Shift Alt (no Ctrl needed, less keyboard gynastics) and click after the last character (bottom-right) of the block to be selected. Works for me on Windows Notepad++ v8.3.3
Allow a few seconds for the whole of the block to be selected (eg 25K lines took 10 secs for cursor reach the bottom of the file)